# How to add description for inbound rule with AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I can create new inbound rule by using following command:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-00b417024c6afddae --protocol tcp --port 5000 --cidr  0.0.0.0/0
```

How can I add the description to that rule?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want to achieve? Individual rules do not have names. You mean rule description?

Comment: @Marcin, yes you are right. I was talking about descriptions. I modified the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use full notation with `--ip-permissions`:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-00b417024c6afddae --ip-permissions FromPort=5000,ToPort=5000,IpProtocol=tcp,IpRanges='[{CidrIp=0.0.0.0/0,Description=mydescription}]'
```